# TestNG suite created programmatically not executing test methods sequaentially

Tags: java, testng

I am struggling to run testNG suite's methods sequentially. However test suite created showing tests methods in correct order but TestNG starts executing them from last. Here is the xml suite generated programmatically:

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="1" name="ABC">
  <test thread-count="1" name="save_for_later">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.xyz.qa.test.webdriver.dgb.client.tests.payments.saveforlater.ClientSaveForLaterTest">
        <methods>
          <include name="saveCCDPaymentTest"/>
          <include name="modifySavedCCDPaymentTest"/>
        </methods>
      </class> <!-- com.xyz.qa.test.webdriver.dgb.client.tests.payments.saveforlater.ClientSaveForLaterTest -->
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- save_for_later -->
</suite> <!-- ABC -->**
```

Here is the code I used to generate suite file. Please suggest any improvement I can do here to get it work:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        if (System.getProperties().containsKey("configurationFile"))
            configurationFile = System.getProperty("configurationFile");
        if (System.getProperties().containsKey("environmentsFile"))
            environmentsFile = System.getProperty("environmentsFile");
        AutomationFramework.loadConfiguration(configurationFile, environmentsFile);
        List<XmlSuite> xmlSuiteList = new ArrayList<>();
        XmlSuite xmlSuite = new XmlSuite();
        xmlSuite.setName("DGB-QA-TEST-AUTOMATION");
        xmlSuite.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.NONE);
        xmlSuite.setPreserveOrder(true);
        List<XmlTest> xmlTestList = null;
        int xmlTestIndex = -1;
        List<Map<String, String>> featureList = db.executeMySQLDatabaseQuery("Select * from test_plan_high_level").getResultSet();
        for (Map<String, String> feature : featureList) {
            XmlTest xmlTest = null;
            if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(feature.get("run"))) {
                if (xmlTestList == null) {
                    xmlTestList = new ArrayList<>();
                }

                xmlTest = new XmlTest(xmlSuite);
                xmlTest.setName(feature.get("feature"));
                xmlTest.setPreserveOrder(true);

                List<Map<String, String>> classList = db.executeMySQLDatabaseQuery("Select " + feature.get("feature") + "_class ," + feature.get("feature") + "_run ,method_column " + " from test_plan_class_level").getResultSet();
                List<XmlClass> xmlClassList = null;
                int xmlClassIndex = -1;
                for (Map<String, String> test_class : classList) {
                    XmlClass xmlClass = null;
                    if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(test_class.get(feature.get("feature") + "_run"))) {
                        if (xmlClassList == null) {
                            xmlClassList = new ArrayList<>();
                        }
                        xmlClass = new XmlClass(test_class.get(feature.get("feature") + "_class"));

                        List<Map<String, String>> methodList = db.executeMySQLDatabaseQuery("select " + test_class.get("method_column") + "," + test_class.get("method_column") + "_run " + " from test_plan_method_level_" + feature.get("feature")).getResultSet();
                        List<XmlInclude> xmlIncludeList = null;
                        int xmlIncludeIndex = -1;
                        for (Map<String, String> method : methodList) {
                            XmlInclude xmlInclude = null;
                            if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(method.get(test_class.get("method_column") + "_run"))) {
                                if (xmlIncludeList == null) {
                                    xmlIncludeList = new ArrayList<>();
                                }
                                xmlInclude = new XmlInclude(method.get(test_class.get("method_column")));
                                xmlIncludeIndex++;
                                xmlIncludeList.add( xmlIncludeIndex,xmlInclude);
                            }
                        }
                        xmlClass.setIncludedMethods(xmlIncludeList);
                        xmlClassIndex++;
                        xmlClassList.add(xmlClassIndex, xmlClass);

                    }

                }
                xmlTest.setClasses(xmlClassList);
                xmlTestIndex++;
                xmlTestList.add(xmlTestIndex, xmlTest);
            }


        }
        xmlSuite.setTests(xmlTestList);
        xmlSuiteList.add(xmlSuite);
        TestNG tng = new TestNG();
        tng.setXmlSuites(xmlSuiteList);
        tng.setUseDefaultListeners(true);
        log.info("Triggering Suite " + xmlSuiteList.get(0).toXml());
        tng.run();

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using preserve-order="true" in the test tag? Please use that and let me know if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Happy to see the reply! Right I set preserver order but 'preserved-order='true' doesn't appear in generated xml suite. I tried setting preserved order at both suite and test level but couldn't resolve this issue. TestNG version i tried 7.0.0. and 7.1.0. Please refer my code I am using to generate suite:

Comment: Somehow it is fixed. Thanks a lot!